# Is it possible to call plugin without short code in WordPress? If not then how to make short code and call plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I want to know how to call plugin without short code. If it is impossible then please tell me how to make short code and how to call plugin for our new created plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your plugins functions without shortcode, just call the function. If the plugin is activated and the function exist it should work.